# easier way to enter data into core data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, sprite-kit

So I have an entity called "Achievement" in my core data model and it holds data that is implemented through a function on the first launch of the application.

[image]

My problem is that I have 30 different achievements in my game that all have different names and amounts and differences from the rest of the achievements, so i'm currently using switch statements to implement it through the function as seen below.

```
func createAchievements(aName: String, Des: String, Image:String, Amount:NSNumber, Needed: NSNumber, Stage: NSNumber, SearchName: String) {

    let A:Achievement = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Achievement", into: CoreDatabaseContoller.getContext()) as! Achievement

    A.theName = aName
    A.theDescription = Des
    A.theImage = Image
    A.aAmount = Amount
    A.aNeededAmount = Needed
    A.aStage = Stage
    A.theSearchName = SearchName

    CoreDatabaseContoller.saveContext()

}




func giveDataForAchievements() {

    if achievementsGenerated == false {

        for count in 1...27 {

            var aName = "None"
            var aDesc = "None"
            var aImage = "locked"
            var aAmount:NSNumber = 0
            var aNeededAmount:NSNumber = 1
            var aStage:NSNumber = 0
            var aSearchName = ""

            switch count {

            case 1:

                aName = "DAILY"
                aDesc = "Daily Achievement"
                aImage = "locked"
                aAmount = 0
                aNeededAmount = 1
                aStage = 3
                aSearchName = "Ach0"

            case 2:

                aName = "DAILY"
                aDesc = "Daily Achievement"
                aImage = "locked"
                aAmount = 0
                aNeededAmount = 1
                aStage = 3
                aSearchName = "Ach1"


       ... plus 30 more of these

     }

     createAchievements(aName: aName, Des: aDesc, Image: aImage, Amount: aAmount, Needed: aNeededAmount, Stage: aStage, SearchName: aSearchName)
  }
```

I was wondering if their is a better way to do this because it looks so bad having long lines of code, the achievement values are changed once they are implemented into core data, its only the initial settings that need to be given to core data

Comment: Is `aSearchName` the only thing you are changing throughout the process?

Comment: No all of the variables including the search name are changing through the process I was just showing an example of how I enter it currently.

Comment: I would save all of the achievement information to a file in a format such as JSON. Then, when the application first launches, take this achievement file and sequentially load each achievement into Core Data.

Comment: I would also suggest a file to load the data from, but plist is probably better; you can create a plist in xcode and read it in easily

Comment: @Paulw11 using the plist should I use an array for each achievement and its variables? do you have link to a tutorial that shows how to do this correctly the way i want to do it?

Comment: Yes, I would use an array of dictionaries.